# Retrieve all data from firebase data link json

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase data link located in app say, `https://appname.firebaseio.com/`.
There is no authentication to firebase links, all data is public. 
We have a custom authentication system. But I am unable to add authentication via custom tokens to firebase because they expire after one hour and I can't force the user to login again.

But I secure the data by adding a sha1 hash for each user in data as label.
So data will link for user will be like:

```
https://appname.firebaseio.com/356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab.json
```

Is this a good method? 
Can a user get all data from `https://appname.firebaseio.com/`, without providing my sha1 embedded url? Is there a way to get all the data or something that I should worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it no a good method.

All data from a public app can be retrieved by this using .json with app url.

```
https://appname.firebaseio.com/.json
```